# Multiple switch selection on button pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's a script that is attached to a game object that has some models inside and I need to change to left/right according.

Ex: I have 3 models
When I press "D" it goes to the 2nd model, if again I press "D" goes to the 3rd model. Pressing "A" goes to the 2nd model and so on.

have tried

```
 if(Input.GeyKeyDown("a")) {   Select(1);}
  else  if(Input.GeyKeyDown("a")) {   Select(2);}  
 else  if(Input.GeyKeyDown("d")) {   Select(1);}
```

I can't get to work.

this is the function i am calling.

```
 public void Select(int index)
    {
        if (index == selectionindex)
            return;

        if (index < 0 || index >= models.Count)
            return;

        models[selectionindex].SetActive(false);
        selectionindex = index;
        models[selectionindex].SetActive(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How do you expect this to ever work?

Lets just look at these two lines for a second:

```
if(Input.GeyKeyDown("a")) { Select(1); }
else if(Input.GeyKeyDown("a")) { Select(2); }
```

If you press "a" and it goes down the first statement is true and calls Select(1).

Then, because it was true, it does not execute the `else` statement.

On another try you don't press "a" and the first statement is false, so it checks the second statement.

Because you didn't press "a" the statement is also false and nothing happens.

### There is no scenario in which `Select(2);` will ever be called.

How do you fix this then?

Well...you know what the current index is already, so...

```
if(Input.GeyKeyDown("a")) { Select(selectionindex-1);}
else if(Input.GeyKeyDown("d")) { Select(selectionindex+1);}
```

Comment: That works as expected, thank you :) and thx for the explanation